# Postgres select as json hash

Tags: json, postgresql

I can select rows as JSON from Postgres e.g.

```
select row_to_json(t)
    from (
      select id, name from accounts
    ) t
```

Which returns each row in this format:

```
{"id":6001,"name":"Foo"}
```

I would like to get them in this format:

```
{ 6001: {"name":"Foo"} }
```

Is this possible?

Edit:

This will get me the proper format for one row:

```
select json_build_object(id,json_build_object('name',name)) from accounts
```

But what I'm ultimately after is all rows in a single hash indexed by key, e.g.

```
{ 
  6001: {"name":"Foo"},
  6002: {"name":"Bar"},
  6003: {"name":"Baz"},
}
```

This gets me closer:

```
select array_to_json(array_agg(json_build_object(id,json_build_object('name',name))))
from accounts
```

But it's still not quite there, producing an array of hashes:

```
[
  { 6001: {"name":"Foo"} },
  { 6002: {"name":"Bar"} },
  { 6003: {"name":"Baz"} },
]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're trying to aggregate, so use [the aggregate function `json_object_agg()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-aggregate.html), which "aggregates name/value pairs as a JSON object". The `id` is your key, and the value you can create with [`json_build_object()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html):

```
select json_object_agg(id, json_build_object('name', name))
from accounts
```

Comment: When I run this, it returns an array of JSON objects like ```[
  { 6001: {"name":"Foo"} },
  { 6002: {"name":"Bar"} },
  { 6003: {"name":"Baz"} },
]
```

Comment: `SELECT
   cm.name,
   cm.short_code,
   cm.timezone,
   ST_Y(map_center::geometry) AS lat,
   ST_X(map_center::geometry) AS lng,
   CONCAT_WS(',',
    ST_YMIN(cz.mpoly::geometry),
    ST_XMIN(cz.mpoly::geometry)
   ) AS tl,
   CONCAT_WS(',',
    ST_YMAX(cz.mpoly::geometry),
    ST_XMAX(cz.mpoly::geometry)
   ) AS br
  FROM
   core_market cm
   JOIN core_zone cz ON (cz.market_id = cm.id)
  WHERE
   deleted = False
   AND cz.active = True
   AND cz.beta = False
  GROUP BY
   cm.name, cm.short_code, cm.timezone,
   cm.map_center, cz.mpoly;`

Comment: @JohnWilliamDomingo what are you posting this SQL statement for? It seems to have nothing to do with this question—there is no JSON involved. Did you mean to post it somewhere else?

Comment: Hi Dan, I am trying to convert that SQL statement to return a hash just like the original question requested. I wasn't sure if I should create my own Q since it is essentially the same as the original question.

Comment: Basically my query has aggregation and where clauses but the example above is a little too simple so I thought I'd piggy back here.

Comment: There is no json aggregation in the query you posted. Check if that's what you meant to post. But yes, if you have a different question, ask a new question with the link above.

Comment: @JohnWilliamDomingo I just retried the answer I posted and it does not give the answer you say it gives. You clearly have a different question, so just post it as a separate question.

Comment: Sorry, the query above returns rows and I'd like to take cm.short_code and make those keys in a json object with the values being the rows also as json objects. `{ short_code1: { name: ..., time_zone: ...},  short_code2: { name: ..., time_zone: ...} }`

Comment: I just figured it out and verified your solution does indeed work

Comment: `SELECT json_object_agg(
  short_code,
  json_build_object(
   'name', cm.name,
   'short_code', cm.short_code,
   'timezone', cm.timezone,
   'lat', ST_Y(map_center::geometry),
   'lng', ST_X(map_center::geometry),
   'tl', CONCAT_WS(',',
    ST_YMIN(cz.mpoly::geometry),
    ST_XMIN(cz.mpoly::geometry)),
   'br', CONCAT_WS(',',
    ST_YMAX(cz.mpoly::geometry),
    ST_XMAX(cz.mpoly::geometry))
 )) AS markets
 FROM
  core_market AS cm
  JOIN core_zone cz ON (cz.market_id = cm.id)
 WHERE
  cm.deleted = False
  AND cz.active = True
  AND cz.beta = False;`

Answer (score -1):

Maybe something like this:

```
select json_build_object(id,json_build_object('name',name)) from accounts
```

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-json.html

Comment: Closer, it works for one row but not what I'm after for multiple results.  I've updated the question above with more detail.